# ¿Puedo cargar imágenes antes de que se muestren?

Tags: python, tkinter

soy muy novato en programación, si digo algo absurdo me puedes corregir.
Estoy haciendo un programa con tkinter en python. Los botones tienen imágenes propias que están descargadas en mi ordenador y se las pongo a los botones con los módulos Image e ImageTk con  `Image.open()` y PhotoImage, introduciendo la ruta donde se encuentra la imagen instalada en mi ordenador, y posteriormente añado la imagen al botón con `self.config(image=imagen)`. Todo funciona bien, el problema es que al cargar unos pocos botones con imagen el programa se cuelga durante unos segundos. ¿Hay alguna manera de evitar esto? Por ejemplo cargando las imágenes antes de que aparezcan, al abrir el programa o algo así...¿? Quizá lo esté haciendo de una manera muy errónea, no he mirado ningún tutorial en profundidad ni nada de eso. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Si se cuelga el programa es porque el hilo que utiliza el método para cargar tus imágenes no ha concluido, sugiero que utilices una forma más eficiente para cargar esas imágenes: establezcas ruta estática de las imágenes o que concluyas cada hilo que inicia tu método. Probablemente se carga de manera sincrónica, y es por ello que se cuelga.
Python no es un lenguaje que conozco, pero la lógica en los lenguages de POO, suelen ser muy similares. Considera buscar alguna librería que cargue de forma asincrónica o con tiempos de ejecución más eficientes.